# Why do we need an Spring MVC or Struts framework if we intend to proceed with single page apps

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, single-page-application

I have a design problem at hand. Traditionally I had been developing Spring MVC/Struts/jsf applications with either REST/SOAP service serving the data.

Now we have HTML5 and other javascript frameworks. In this light, do we still need to create Spring MVC applicationS as such (assume that the data is served from a RESTful service)

If I go ahead with pure HTML5, CSS UI (with Ajax calls to RESTful services), what are the possible issues that I may get into? does this approach have security holes like being prone to cross site scripting?

Is it a good approach to start off with? Would this approach be called a single page app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You still need to serve your single page app from somewhere, along w images and css files. This could be a Spring MVC servlet, or whatever.
2. I'd look into [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) which is a servlet that creates RESTful HATEOAS endpoints for you.

It's probably easier if your SPA and REST service are on the same domain, so you don't have to worry about cross-domain [restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

They are still vulnerable to XSS, as is any system unless you take counter-measures. Spring security can help here. Make sure you follow the OWASP [guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Use Hibernate Validator's `@SafeHTML` annotation to prevent unsafe HTML input into your database. Use Spring Security's `<content-type-options/>` , `<xss-protection/>` , and `<header name="Content-Security-Policy" value="..."/>` settings to help fight XSS.

Comment: I got the point, the second point leaves me even more perplexed.Spring data is exposing the data base as rest end points and in my case this would be queried from javascript frameworks. is n't leaving a  big security hole? like sql injection.with some few lines of javascripting  get the hackers the entire DB is n't this case. XSS counter measures can only be in the server side isn't ?

Comment: 1. Spring Data Rest is not vulnerable to SQL Injection, as it uses parameterization. 2. If the JavaScript runs on another domain they cannot access your domain, unless you specifically allow them with CORS on your server. 3. Use Spring Security 3.2+ for XSS and CSRF counter-measures.

Comment: Cool I had never tried Spring rest data, well there is first time for everything.. thanks a lot for the suggestions!!!

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC, Struts, etc. provide two core functions: Routing, and Binding.

Routing is dispatching an HTTP request to the relevant piece of code.

Binding is converting the world of Strings that the HTTP request sends you in to something more useful, such as a generic Java bean with not just Strings, but integers and dates.

Along for the ride are aspects such as validation.

Finally, they provide an environment that's particularly friendly to your view layer.

None of these aspects, per se, are obsolete in a world where all you have is JSON coming up and JSON heading back. You still need routing, but now you may care to route not simply on the request url itself, but on HTTP verb. You still need binding, having the framework marshal the JSON payload into some easier for java to work with is very handy.

But, (and I speak in general terms, not specifics as I don't know Spring or Struts well at all), while the MVC frameworks can fill the role of a backend system for a more JSON oriented and raw HTTP world, the specific REST frameworks do the job better.

There's no mistake that the MVC frameworks were a significant step up over raw Servlets. Raw Servlets are functional, but simply too primitive for real work. But with design decisions made from a world 10 years ago, some parts show their age and get in the way in the new world of more raw HTTP requests.

If you're doing a mixed app, some MVC, and some HTTP/Ajax methods, then it's better to work with your MVC framework than adopt a new one.

If you're doing a pure singe page app, then it's worth your while to adopt a framework that tends to that niche. They'll simply be a better fit.

Mind, also, they can live side by side. You can have both co-habitate in a single WAR if you wish, particularly if you're adding SPA features to a legacy application. It doesn't have to be an either/or situation.

But I wouldn't introduce an entire new infrastructure component simply to handle a couple of ajax calls. In the end, they're just HTTP calls, and the MVC frameworks (in contrast to most component frameworks) do just fine with raw HTTP for the most part.

Comment: 1. Routing 2.Binding 3.Validation : with HTML5 we be able to do all three within the browser itself. so what I am to infer is that there is nothing wrong in pursuing this approach of totally client driven except for the data . (assuming Cross side scripting is addressed on the server side)

Comment: @harry you still need to do all of these things on the server. Routing to determine what code to run, binding to convert the strings you get in to things you can work with, validation because you can never (ever) trust what you get from the client.